# マイクロソフトAzure - WebDAVでエラー

Tags: azure

サーバー間でWebDAV接続のファイル共有を行うように考えています。

サーバーはどちらもWindows2012 r2です。
どちらもWebDAV発行を行っております。
他クラウドのAサーバー、Azureサーバーがございます。
１．AサーバーのフォルダーはAzureサーバーから接続可能。
２．AzureサーバーのフォルダーはAサーバーから接続不可能の状態です。
WebDAVの設定などは同じに設定しておりますが、２．接続できません。

上記以外でも、WindowsSV2008とかWindows7/8とかでの接続状況があるのですが、
パターンが多くなるので、まずは上記だけ、書いています。
接続エラーは「System error 64」です。
まず、どこをチェックするれば良いでしょうか？

↑上記の補足です。

Azureサーバー（WinSV2012R2）に対しての接続（https）
OK：Win7 / Win8.1 から
NG：Win10 / WinSV2012R2 / WinSV2008　から

また、NGのPCに、WebDAVクライアントソフト（CarotDAV、NetDrive）をインストール・接続すると問題なく接続・ネットドライブ設定ができる。
できれば、Windows標準のネットワークドライブ設定で、共有を実現したいのですが・・・

ネット上で、「WebDAVのWindowsでの実装が良くないので不安定」との記事を見かけるが、
何が良くないのか、よく分かりません？
OSの違い？OSバージョン？ネットワーク設定？認証？
Win標準のWebClientを更新すれば改善される？

何か、アドバイスがございましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/ae54f94d-248f-4df0-98d7-1c687258b406/webdav?forum=windowsazureja

Answer (score 1):

SSL認証を使用しないWebDavへの接続はWindowsクライアント側で使用できないようになっています。

・・・が、Windows7でもダメなはずで現に私のWindows7環境から
自前で立ち上げているSSL認証していないWebDAVサーバーの接続へは
レジストリ改変を行って接続したり、補足情報で書かれたようなWebDavクライアントを使用しています。
レジストリ改変参考URL:http://support.kagoya.jp/kir/manual/webdav/win7/

ご質問のWebDAVサーバーの証明書が作成されていなかったり、クライアント側で証明書のインポートを行っていないならば同原因かと思います。
(OK状況が当方と異なりますので違いそうですが・・・)

＞Win標準のWebClientを更新すれば改善される？
原因が上記のようなことであった場合、Windows標準のClientは制限を厳しくする側に倒れて行っているので余計厳しくなると思います。